# Sort a vector of custom object types based on date (POSIXlt) in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have defined a custom class `myType` like so:

```
myType <- function(s="", n="", m=c())
{
    structure(list("start"=s, "name"=n, "moves"=m), class="myType")
}
```

In my program I have generated a `vector` of `myType` objects. What I need to do is sort this vector of `myType` objects using the `start` element of `myType` which is a `POSIXlt` type.

Can anyone show me the way to go?

Comment: Your object is a list, so I'm skeptical that you have a vector of these objects. Can you provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: A list of things is a vector of things :) `is.vector(list(c(1,2),3,"foo"))` is `TRUE`

Comment: @Thomas You're right. I was using the c() function to add the `myType` but when I checked the type it is indeed a list. Sorry, I'm very new to R and coming from a C++ background this is confusing to say the least.

Comment: @Spacedman `is.vector(structure(list("start"=1, "name"=2, "moves"=3), class="myType"))`

Comment: S/He can still have a vector of `myType` objects `is.vector(list(myType(),myType(),myType()))` is `TRUE`

Comment: @Spacedman Intriguing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `POSIXlt`? did you need to manipulate date time attributes like hours , min day,..? If not it is better to use `POSIXct'.`POSIXlt` is a list and hard to manipulate.

That's said, if `ll` is your list of objects, you can use `order` to sort it by `start` slot. The idea is to create first a simpler vector of `POSIXct`.

```
ll[order(unlist(lapply(ll,function(x)as.POSIXct(x$start))))]
```

where `ll` can be generated as:

```
ll <- lapply(1:10,function(x)
    myType(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()+sample(1000:2000,1))))
```

Comment: POSIXlt was simply the type the previous author of the code used. I'm new to R so I was unaware of the difference. I've read that it's possible to write a custom xtfrm function and call sort, is this a more efficient way?